# Gemfire cache "PDXInstance to Json" Joda DateTime error

Tags: json, spring, jodatime, gemfire

I am trying to get PDXInstances from the Gemfire cache and convert them to JSON but its failing when a Joda DateTime is encountered.

Please see the error below -

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: PdxInstance returns unknwon pdxfield inServiceDate for type Fri Jun 18 00:00:00 CDT 1971
```

I am doing the below -

```
JSONFormatter.toJSON(pdxInstance)
```

Reference:
http://pubs.vmware.com/vfabric53/index.jsp?topic=/com.vmware.vfabric.gemfire.7.0/developing/data_serialization/jsonformatter_pdxinstances.html

Anybody encountered this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I posted the same on gemfire forums and they told me that JSONFormatter is not mature enough to handle custom objects or JODA Data types. Hope this helps..